# Passing props from parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render a Feed Component in layout,but I'm not able to pass the props.

this the layout component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import classes from "./Layout.css";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Aux from "../Aux/Aux";
import Feed from "../Feed/Feed";

class Layout extends Component {
  state = {
    users: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://goodwill-60d8a.firebaseio.com/Users.json")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    let feed = () => {
      return (
        <Aux>
          <Feed users={this.state.users} />
        </Aux>
      );
    };
    return (
      <div className={classes.main}>
        <div>
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={feed} />
            <Route path="/fullpost" component={FullPost} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

this is the feed component

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import classes from "./Feed.css";

const feed = (props) => {
  const feedItems = Object.keys(props.users).map((key) => ({
    id: props.users,
    ...props.users[key],
  }));
  return (
    <div className={classes.feed}>
      {feedItems.map((items) => (
        <Post
          key={items.id}
          profileName={items.profileName}
          profilePic={items.profilePic}
          timeStamp={items.timeStamp}
          contentImage={items.contentImage}
          contentText={items.contentText}
          trend={items.trend}
        ></Post>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default feed;
```

this the post component.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Post.css";
import ShareButton from "../../UI/ShareButton/ShareButton";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const post = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.post}>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        <div className={classes.profileimage}>
          <img className={classes.pic} src={props.profilePic} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.name}>{props.profileName}</div>
        <div className={classes.timestamp}>{props.timeStamp}</div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div className={classes.image}>
          <img src={props.contentImage} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className={classes.text}>
            <span>{props.contentText}</span>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.fullpost}>
            <Link to="/fullpost">See Full Post</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.footer}>
        <div className={classes.trend}>
          <span>{props.trend}</span>
        </div>
        <ShareButton />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default post;
```

Im getting a type error:cannot convert undefined or null to a object. What I want to do is to render a component which gets the http response in the layout component.the response needs to passed down to feed component, which renders post component.Im not able to pass the http response to Feed Component.

Comment: On which line is the error you are getting?

Comment: can you please reproduce the problem using CodeSandbox?

Comment: ```const feedItems = Object.keys(props.users).map((key) => ({
    id: props.users,
    ...props.users[key],
  }));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is probably breaking here

```
const feedItems = Object.keys(props.users).map((key) => ({
    id: props.users,
    ...props.users[key],
  }));
```

While your API request is resolving the value of props.users is null.
You can:

1. Add a default value to users state, make it an empty object.
2. Add a default value to users prop
3. Add a check before running Object.keys to see if the object is not null or undefined.